# inserting records in mysql leading to thread count increase

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, java-threads

I have created two thread "READ_THREAD" and "WRITE_THREAD" whhich are running continuously with some sleep interval as shown in below code. When i run this code without database insert query and print thread count, it gives 3 always. But when i add insert query in the code, thread count gets increased to 4 and over course of time...it keeps on increasing. What wrong i am doing ?

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingcomUC1SerialRunnableThreadClass t1 = new SingcomUC1SerialRunnableThreadClass("READ_THREAD");
        t1.start1();
        SingcomUC1SerialRunnableThreadClass t2 = new SingcomUC1SerialRunnableThreadClass("Write_THREAD");
        t2.start1();
        System.out.println("active thread count=" + Thread.activeCount());
    }
}

public class SingcomUC1SerialRunnableThreadClass implements Runnable {

    Thread t;
    String threadName;
    String singcomUC1Readthread="READ_THREAD";
    String singcomUC1Writethread="Write_THREAD";


    public SingcomUC1SerialRunnableThreadClass(String name) {
        threadName = name;
    }

    public void start1() {
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run() invokations");
        while (true) {
            if (threadName.equalsIgnoreCase(singcomUC1Readthread)) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "--" + Thread.activeCount());
                try {
                    commonSection();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SingcomUC1SerialRunnableThreadClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SingcomUC1SerialRunnableThreadClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if (threadName.equalsIgnoreCase(singcomUC1Writethread)) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "--" + Thread.activeCount());
                try {
                    commonSection();
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SingcomUC1SerialRunnableThreadClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void commonSection() throws InterruptedException {
        InsertValuesIntoUC1DBtable.insertDefaultValueAndStatusIntoUC1DBtable(singcomUC1DeviceId);
        ReadOrUpdateUC1CONTROLtable.insertDefaultValueAndStatusIntoDC1DBtable(singcomUC1DeviceId);
    }
}

public class InsertValuesIntoUC1DBtable {

    public static void insertDefaultValueAndStatusIntoUC1DBtable(int deviceid) {
        try {
            Connection con = null;
            DatabaseConnection databaseConnection_obj = new DatabaseConnection();
            con = databaseConnection_obj.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from uc1db");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into uc1db(deviceid,frequency,attenuation,transmitterstatus,devicestatus) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
                pst.setInt(1, deviceid);
                pst.setString(2, "0");
                pst.setString(3, "0");
                pst.setString(4, "0");
                pst.setString(5, "online");
                pst.executeUpdate();
            }
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
            con.close();
        } //**
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InsertValuesIntoUC1DBtable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class DatabaseConnection {

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "admin");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Db Exception  " + e);
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
active thread count=3
run() invokations
run() invokations
singcomUC1ReadThread--2
singcomUC1WriteThread--2
singcomUC1WriteThread--4
singcomUC1WriteThread--4
```

Comment: Where are your singcomUC1Readthread & singcomUC1Writethread vars defined ?

Answer (score 0):

So, what are those elusive threads you ask?

You can get some insights by running `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().list()`

That's what the output may look like:

```
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
    Thread[READ_THREAD,5,main]
    Thread[Write_THREAD,5,main]
    Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]
    Thread[mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup,5,main]
```

The first two you probably recognise.

`DestroyJavaVM` is a maintenance thread that makes sure that all other threads have completed before terminating the VM.

`mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup` is very similar, but for MySQL Connector.

Do note, that you shouldn't be worried about those maintenance threads. They are usually written by very proficient people, that make sure those threads won't affect performance of your application. What you should be more worried about, is your own threads, and more specifically, not using thread pool to manage them.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct then, for others to use.